# Hive importing a string date given as "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" from csv as timestamp

Tags: timestamp, hive, csv-import

My csv file looks like this:

```
"SMTEX","GSN","KOF",1.71,"2014-01-06 13:32:21"
"NXEX","JS","FIM",1.99,"2014-01-14 09:52:11"
"SMTEX","WT","VUX",0.82,"2014-01-23 02:22:37"
```

I import this data into hive by:

```
hive -e 'CREATE TABLE playground.stuff (
             ex_id STRING,
             game_id  STRING,
             user_id       STRING,
             price         FLOAT,
             date          TIMESTAMP)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";'
hive -e 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "/path/to/csv" INTO TABLE playground.stuff;'
```

However the timestamp seems not to be parsed. The output I get is:

```
hive> select * from stuff;
OK
"SMTEX" "GSN"   "KOF"   1.71    NULL
"NXEX"  "JS"    "FIM"   1.99    NULL
"SMTEX" "WT"    "VUX"   0.82    NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ssupect it's the double quotes. The format should be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss". You'll notice the double quotes also end up in the string fields.

Edit answer based on comment:

Hive doesn't support double quotes natively however there is a csv serde which can do this for you: https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde

Comment: Yeah that's right. I was actually able to import the timestamp when omitting the quotes. However, I was wondering if there is a possibility to tell hive explicitly how to understand the format.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jar on Github(https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar. Download it and add the jar while running Hive queries in the command prompt.

(excerpted from the above Github link)

add jar path/to/csv-serde.jar;

create table my_table(a string, b string, ...)
  row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
  stored as textfile
;

This solved the problem for me with quoted values.

If you are using Hue to upload quoted csv data into Hive, then follow the below video. 
http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-create-hive-tables-with-headers-and/

Answer (score 0):

Given the formatting string in the title of this post, beware that the common casing for date/time formats is of importance when using library parsing functions.

**MM** represents months whereas **mm** represent minutes; not to be confused.

**HH** for 24h notation versus **hh** for 12 hour notation is another example that could matter.